# Change fully convolutional network input shape in TF 2.3 and tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm working with tensorflow 2.3 and `tf.keras`

I've trained a network on images with input shape `(None,120,120,12)` . Actually I've also been able to train the model while declaring the input as `(None,128,128,12)` while feeding `(None,120,120,12)` batches because of a coding error. TF just printed out a warning and didn't care. This wasn't the behavior in previous versions. My network has only convolutional layers and, if the input size has enough powers of 2 considering the depth, it provides an output image of the same shape as the input, it has only convolutional layers.

I've finally fully trained this model and I'd like to apply it also to images of different shape. Is there a proper way to change the input shape of my trained model? Or should I define a new model and then copy the weights layer by layer? Or should I just forget about it and just accept the warnings and forget about them since it works anyway?

Answer (score 0):

ah. You again. I think your problem is basically simple. Once you train your model with an input size. If you want to run the model, the input must be the same shape. However, if you want to take advantage of the trained model and believe that the features have learnt is not much different, then you can apply transferlearning, and of course, retrain it again. You don't have to copy weights, just freeze the model and train only the input and output. You can check [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/06/24/change-input-shape-dimensions-for-fine-tuning-with-keras/) for some basic example with your VGG

```
base_model = tensorflow.keras.applications.VGG19(
        weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
        input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
        include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = layers.Input(shape=150,150,3)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 150, 150, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
vgg19 (Model)                multiple                  20024384  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
```

Comment: No, the input doesn't have to be the same shape. Indeed now in TF2.3 I can train a model on 128x128 and it will run on a 256x256 with just a warning (and good accuracy). I don't have any dense layer so there's no size mismatch. I've read the link you've given here multiple times, but it applies only to models that keras provide, while I have my own one!

Comment: good accuracy is strange, but according to you your model does not have dense layers, so it is reasonable. However like I just suggest, take advantage of freezing model instead of copying layers by layers is better,

Comment: There are reasons for why I expect decent accuracy specific to my issue (microscopy with fixed pixel size, 128x128 are patches, 256x256 are whole image). But that's mostly unrelated to programming. So, how do I "freeze" my model. The weights aren't getting updated anyway in inference. I can't find a way to say change the input size of a model for an arbitrary model

Comment: You just need to declare an input layer with a different shape and connect it with the freeze layers you choose. You can select a range of layers to freeze: 
`for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:]:
    layer.trainable = False`
the link I gave you is an example of reusing  a model with a different iput

Comment: I understand easily how to freeze layers. I don't understand however how to connect to an existing model I created (not one of the ones already present in keras, like they do in your link) a different layer! I mean... I got it how to connect a layer to an existing output, but not how to inject a different input after chopping out some layers

Comment: yes, of course that is not a fill solution. I want you to understand the idea only. Because, normally, you want to train a size of image to well operate at some fixed size and all you need to do then for bigger images is scaling them back to that original size. However, in order to save your time. You can check scratch code I write here